# Examples of real world projects on angularjs with source code

Tags: angularjs

My team is just starting to learn AngularJs. We have gone through a series of tutorials but we want to see some real world apps to see how things are done in a real working app.

I made some research but was able to find only [this project](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app) with source code on GitHub.

I will be very grateful if some good people share more apps like this. In my opinion, this is a very good way to get real experience about some new technology.

Comment: I have created an app 

http://lookaround.herokuapp.com

This one doesn't do any CRUD operations , but will demonstrate how to work with 3rd party APIs and creating custom directives. I have used Google Maps and Google Places APIs with AngularJS

Comment: Is it appropriate to share some sample code. Mainly the code structure - a controller, service, directive ... as much as not revelealing the important logic of your app. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it's already in Github:

https://github.com/shidhincr/LookAround

Comment: Another repo is a jukebox player: https://github.com/jimmykane/theofficejukebox and live example: http://theofficejukebox.appspot.com/
which is built on appengine, angular and only SAAS. All are json requests.

Comment: Check this one.Great one. https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManagerStandard

Comment: Have you checked this collection? https://github.com/jiwonbest/amazing-angular-projects

Answer (score 4):

Goodfil.ms and doubleclick are good examples. If you're looking at hybrid apps take a look at the Sky Sports Cricket score centre with a Cordova type wrapper. Most people won't disclose code of these large projects but Yeoman (yo angular) and seed projects (angular, requirejs, gulp, Browserify) give you a good starting point. You'll also see a lot of examples through the angular documentation to help you get started.

Comment: In 2020 Goodfil.ms and doubleclick seems unavailable as open-source on Github. At least I couldn't find it